# SSRS 2012 display Bing map image

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have created sql to retrieve information from our table and create the url for a Bing map. If I take the url from the query and paste it into a browser the map image appears.

Example: `https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Imagery/Map/Road?mapSize=600,600&mapLayer=TrafficFlow&format=png&pushpin=35.96981750,-85.03747790;64;1&key=xxx`

But in SSRS if I use the url as an external image I get the red-X-in-box. No error message but no image either.

I read there should be a way to "enable external images". I've checked the box for the image. Is there another place to change the setting?

Comment: If you use an external image url you should be able to see it at design time. Try inserting a new image, setting its source to external and past this url directly into the value (no quotes etc, just as it is..)  `https://www.google.co.uk/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png` . This should show you the standard google logo, even at design time. If that works swap it for your image url and test again.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The Google image worked and my map appeared when I copy/pasted the url to the Image Properties. But if I'm building the URL through SQL how can I make it appear? Using the formula to enter the field containing the URL doesn't work.

Comment: I can't replicate your issue. I used the google image url from a dataset and it worked as expected. Can you update your question to show exactly how you are trying to do this, is the image in a table or on it's own, what expression are you using in the image value etc. Show screen shots if you can. Also try adding a text box with the URL text from your dataset then setting the placeholder properties to HTML and you should have a clickable link that works.

Comment: As I can reproduce your map using your exact URL (except for the key) I'll post an answer that you can follow along and hopefully it will highlight whats wrong with your report.

Comment: Your example works. Now I just have to figure out why my url is diff than yours.

Comment: Got it to work. This is AWESOME,AWESOME,AWESOME!

Comment: Great news, glad you got therein the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can produce your map without any issues. Follow these instructions and make sure you can reproduce the same results, , then compare to your own report. Hopefully the issue will become apparent.

Create a new Report.
Create a new Dataset called `BingMapSample` and use the following dataset query, swapping the key for **your** Bing maps key

```
    -- set up some static values
    DECLARE @BingmapKey varchar(256) = 'XxXX-99x-
9XXXXX9XXxxxXXXxXxXxxxxXxXxx9X9XxxX9xxXxXX9xXXx99x9XXxx'
    DECLARE @MapSize varchar(10) = '600'
    DECLARE @Layer varchar(256) = 'TrafficFlow'

    -- stick a few locations in a table, the first one is from your exmaple
    DECLARE @mapLocations TABLE (coords varchar(256))
    INSERT INTO @mapLocations VALUES
        ('35.96981750,-85.03747790'),
        ('50.998647,-0.105406')


    -- now build up some urls to use in the report
    SELECT 
           'https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Imagery/Map/Road?mapSize=' + @MapSize + ',' + @MapSize 
           + '&mapLayer=' + @Layer 
           + '&format=png&pushpin=' + ml.coords
           + ';64;1&key=' + @BingmapKey
           AS BingMapSampleURL
        FROM @mapLocations ml
```

Now add an image to your report (use a sensible size) and set the following

- Source = `External`
- Value = `=First(Fields!BingMapSampleURL.Value, "BingMapSample")`

If you run the report you should see your map displayed.

To show both maps in a list, do the following

Add a 'List' to your report and set

- DataSetName = `BingMapSample`

Resize the list's only cell to something sensible then **inside** the list 'cell' insert an image. Set the image properties as follows

- Source = `External`
- Value = `=Fields!BingMapSampleURL.Value`

The final design looked like this... (I shaded the list background just for clarity).

[image]

If you run the report you should now also see two more maps, three maps in total.

When I run the report I get this

[image]

Hope that helps...